# Query to return data where Id Column is unique but display number is the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table like below:

```
CustomerId   OrderId  NoToDisplay
123           176        1
123           177        1
124           125        1
124           126        2
124           127        3
125           182        6
125           183        6
```

I am trying to write a query that returns unique order numbers that have got the same NoToDisplay Value.  So from the dataset snippet above the output would be:

```
CustomerId   OrderId  NoToDisplay
123           176        1
123           177        1
125           182        6
125           183        6
```

This is the query I have tried but it isn't returning what I expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.NoToDisplay
FROM Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
WHERE o.OrderID IN (SELECT DISTINCT o.NoToDisplay
FROM Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
GROUP BY o.NoToDisplay HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want customers where the `NoToDisplay` values are all the same.  To get the customers:

```
select customerid
from t
group by customerid
having min(NoToDisplay) = max(NoToDisplay);
```

You can easily extend this to get the original rows:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select customerid
      from t
      group by customerid
      having min(NoToDisplay) = max(NoToDisplay)
     ) tc
     on t.customerid = tc.customerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from Customer 
where customerid not in
(select customerid 
 from Customer 
 group by customerid 
 having count(distinct notodisplay) >1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
declare @Customer  table
(CustomerId int,   OrderId int,  NoToDisplay int)
insert into @Customer
select 123 ,          176  ,      1 union all
select 123 ,          177  ,      1 union all
select 124 ,          125  ,      1 union all
select 124 ,          126  ,      2 union all
select 124 ,          127  ,      3 union all
select 125 ,          182  ,      6 union all
select 125 ,          183  ,      6

select CustomerID, OrderId, NoToDisplay 
from
(select CustomerID, OrderId, NoToDisplay, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, NoToDisplay) [check]
from @Customer 
group by CustomerID, OrderID, NoToDisplay) x
where [check] > 1
order by CustomerID
```